# Pass touches from a gesture recognizer to a tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIViewController` that has a child view which contains a `UITableViewContoller` with disabled interaction. I'm currently using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` that drags the parent `UIViewController` and enables the `UITableViewController` once its y origin is dragged past a certain y coordinate.

Right now, once the `UITableViewController` is enabled, I need to remove my finger and retap in order to start controlling it. Is there a way to switch focus from the gesture recognizer to the table view as soon as it hits the enabled threshold, so when a user continues scrolling it will start to affect the table view?

Comment: not yet, still researching this one.

Comment: why dont you try removing the gesture recognizer once it reaches that point and create a new one once it needs one?

Comment: did you try updating the gesture property cancelsTouchesInView when you want to control the TableView? Maybe you could subclass the GestureRecognizer and deliver the touches. Also, you could try creating two different GestureRecognizers and switch between them when necessary.

Comment: You can also try, adding UITableView as KVO observer, for the "frame' property of ParentView, and move the TableView when the parentView had reached the limit, using the same PanGesture which is added to the parentView.